# Can't use dict.values() with min func's key

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I created a dict:

```
scores = {5: 35044.51299744237, 25: 29016.41319191076, 50: 27405.930473214907, 100: 27282.50803885739, 250: 27893.822225701646, 500: 29454.18598068598}
```

I can use min function with it using:

```
min(scores.keys(),key = lambda x: scores[x])
min(scores, key=scores.get)
```

but when I try to use:

```
min(scores.keys(),key = scores.values())
```

I get an error :

> 'dict_values' object is not callable

Could someone please explain why?

Comment: Why should it work?

Comment: key is a function you apply to each element of iterator to determine a real value to be compared. When you pass key=scores.values(), you get DictValues object (something like list), it's not a function

Comment: `key` should a function to which each item of the iterable is passed. And the function should return a value by which the `min` is found.

Comment: Because you are calling `scores.values()` directly, which returns a `dict_values` object as the key function for `min`. Min tries to call this `dict_values` as a function. Since its no function (not callable), the mentioned error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

`key` must be a function callable with one parameter. `values()` is not a function, it's a view, a sequence of all values in the dict. And while `scores.values` is a function it's not callable with a parameter.

It's also unclear as to what you think your snippet would actually do even if it worked. What would looking for a key in the set of values do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You get `'dict_values' object is not callable` because the `key` argument in `min` requires a callable object (an object that has `__call__` method). In your case `scores.values()` returns an object with type `<class 'dict_values'>` that is not callable.

```
>>> dct = {}
>>> type(dct.values())
<class 'dict_values'>
>>> callable(dct.values())
False
```

If you wish to get the key with the minimal value, you should try something like this.

```
min(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Or with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
min(scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

In other words, `min` applies `key` function to the elements provided by `scores.items()`.

If you try `scores.keys()`, as in your question, `min` function knows nothing about its values. Though you still can do this:

```
min(scores.keys(), key=lambda key: scores[key])
```

But I wouldn't recommend this solution, because `key` function contains `scores` inside that can lead to undefined behavior in some cases.